# Pandas get positions of intersection between 2 indexes

Tags: python, pandas

If I have 2 Pandas dataframe indexes, idx1 and idx2, how I can get the index positions (from the original indexes) of the intersection:

```
idx1 = pd.Index([1, 2, 3, 4])
idx2 = pd.Index([3, 4, 5, 6])
intersect = idx1.intersection(idx2)
```

Looking for [2, 3] for idx1 and [0, 1] for idx 2.

This doesn't work:

```
idx1.get_loc(intersect)
```

I can do a loop to get these values, but is there something better?

```
for x in intersect:
    print(idx1.get_loc(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the index is unique, you can use `get_indexer`:

```
idx1.get_indexer(intersect)
# array([2, 3])

idx2.get_indexer(intersect)
# array([0, 1])
```

If the index is not unique, then you need `isin` method with `numpy.where`:

```
pd.np.where(idx1.isin(intersect))[0]
# array([2, 3])

pd.np.where(idx2.isin(intersect))[0]
# array([0, 1])
```